# Elasticsearch matching names with initial

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch search template mustache language

Searching 'Joe Gray' returns anybody named 'Joe Gray' or searching "J Gray" returns "Joe Gray".

But searching 'Joe Gray' does not return any names with 'J Gray'

how can I achieve this with using analyzer in my mustache query.

Comment: is all your data in the form of: <first name> <last name>? or does it vary in structure?.

Comment: firstname is indexed separately. I want to search for "Joe" and should get a match for "J".

Comment: Again, is the data you save ONLY in the form of <first name> <last name> ? or do you have something like : word word word firstname lastname word word word. i hope this is clear enough.

Comment: ah, yes data is saved in the form of <first name> <last name>

Comment: one more clarification, any middle names ? and if so in what format do you want those.

Comment: i dont have middle name. if I search for personname: Joe Gray ,my search result looks something like: {
"lastnames" : "Gray",
"firstname" : "Joe"
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure what your index mapping looks like. I have two examples here:

1 **Name is contained in one field:**

```
    PUT t2/doc/1
    {
      "name":"Joe Gray"
    }

    PUT t2/doc/2
    {
      "name":"J Gray"
    }

    POST t2/_search
    {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "name": "j gray"
        }
      }
    }

##Result

{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 0.51623213,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "t2",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.51623213,
        "_source": {
          "name": "J Gray"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "t2",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.25811607,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Joe Gray"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

2 If you have your **name as two separate fields**(from what i noticed in the comments) - you can use a `bool` query with `should` clause:

```
PUT t3/doc/1
{
  "firstname":"Joe",
  "lastname":"Gray"
}

PUT t3/doc/2
{
  "firstname":"J",
  "lastname":"Gray"
}


POST t3/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "firstname": "J"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "lastname": "Gray"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

## Result

{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 0.5753642,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "t3",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.5753642,
        "_source": {
          "firstname": "J",
          "lastname": "Gray"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "t3",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "firstname": "Joe",
          "lastname": "Gray"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```